# float: left property

Tags: html, css, css-float, position

On my webpage when I'm using float: left for the navigation bar buttons (to line up horizontal) it makes content after that move to the right, such as:

```
[ Home About More ]
                   Text
```

I want it to be:

```
[ Home About More ]
Text
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Looks like you need a clearfix, can you post the code?

Comment: you can allways try using one div for each element, float both divs to the left and set the width of both divs to that of the main div

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use the `clear` attribute in Text. Like so:

```
.text {clear:left}
```

Comment: I knew that, I'm just tired! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Use the clearfix solution to fix the issue.

http://themergency.com/css-clearfix-demystified/

UPDATE:
In the CSS file, add the following:

```
.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after { content: ""; display: table; }
.clearfix:after { clear: both; }
.clearfix { zoom: 1; }
```

Then in your HTML, add the `clearfix` class to the parent container of the floated elements. Not sure what your HTML markup looks like but it may be something along the lines of with the clearfix solution:

```
<div class="clearfix">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">More</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a very common issue, I would recommend defining a css entry like so

`.clear {clear:both;}`

Then in the future you can simply add this class to an element that requires the above floats to be cleared, or simply add an empty div with this class like so.

`<div class="clear"></div>`

Comment: This is the "old school" method to fix the issue, which also works, but isn't a best practice as you're adding extra (empty) HTML markup to fix positioning/layout issues. You should be using a pure CSS solution to fix it as best practice IMO.

Comment: I agree that having empty markup is bad practice, however, having a re-usable class isn't.

Comment: How is using a RE-USABLE CSS class not more efficient and best practice? You reduce unnecessary HTML tags and you're using a class that will most likely be used multiple times? Adding empty HTML tags is inefficient. IMO, a re-usable class IS the best way.

Answer (score 0):

Or this works to (overflow trick):

```
<div style="overflow:auto">
   <div style="float:left">[ Home </div>
   <div style="float:left">About </div>
   <div style="float:left">More ]</div>
</div>
Your other text
```